# MySQL Field Length Errors

Tags: mysql

Just moved a site over to a new server and we started getting some errors. Mainly that some data we were passing into a MySQL table was too long for the field. Having checked through the DB it seems the old server was truncating the data to fit the table, yet the new server throws a TEP STOP. Any ideas what the setting is to switch this back on, to temporarily get stuff working again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL used to be famous/infamous for silently "correcting" data it could not store directly (overlong strings, invalid dates) etc.. That has fortunately changed in recent versions.

You can now configure this behaviour using "Server SQL Modes". You probably want to switch off STRICT_ALL_TABLES or STRICT_TRANS_TABLES.

See [MySQL's docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html) for details.